# batch modify video files preserving date of creation in new files

Tags: shell-script

I made a script to reduce the size of .mov and .mp4 videos with avconv, and skipping already compressed videos (by string presence). In the script I put the date of the video in the name, but I would prefer preserving the original date of the video in the shrinked file as an attribute, which of course in the script is not implemented. Is it possible in linux console?

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s globstar || exit
for f in **
do
  if [[ "$f" =~ \.mp4$ ]] || [[ "$f" =~ \.mov$ ]] || [[ "$f" =~ \.MOV$ ]] ; then
    if [[ "$f" =~ reduced.*\.mp4$ ]] || [[ "$f" =~ compressed.*\.mp4$ ]]; then
    echo "already compressed"
    else
      if yes |      avconv -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -crf 24 -c:a aac -strict -2 "${f%.*}_$(date -d@$(stat --printf='%Y' "$f") +%Y%m%d)"_compressed.mp4; then
      rm -Rf "$f"
      else
      rm -Rf "${f%.*}_$(date -d@$(stat --printf='%Y' "$f") +%Y%m%d)"_compressed.mp4
      echo "Command failed"
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using `touch`:

```
else
  t="${f%.*}_$(date -d@$(stat --printf='%Y' "$f") +%Y%m%d)"_compressed.mp4
  if yes |      avconv -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -crf 24 -c:a aac -strict -2 "$t"; then
    touch -r "$f" "$t"
    rm -f "$f"
  else
    rm -f "$t"
    echo "Command failed"
  fi
fi
```

The `-r` option tells `touch` to use the given file as a reference for the times to apply to the target file.